# How to determine an interface{} value's "real" type?

Tags: types, type-conversion, go

I have not found a good resource for using `interface{}` types. For example

```
package main

import "fmt"

func weirdFunc(i int) interface{} {
    if i == 0 {
        return "zero"
    }
    return i
}
func main() {
    var i = 5
    var w = weirdFunc(5)

    // this example works!
    if tmp, ok := w.(int); ok {
        i += tmp
    }

    fmt.Println("i =", i)
}
```

Do you know of a good introduction to using Go's `interface{}`?

specific questions:

- how do I get the "real" Type of w?
- is there any way to get the string representation of a type?
- is there any way to use the string representation of a type to
  convert a value?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Your example does work. Here's a simplified version.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func weird(i int) interface{} {
    if i < 0 {
        return "negative"
    }
    return i
}

func main() {
    var i = 42
    if w, ok := weird(7).(int); ok {
        i += w
    }
    if w, ok := weird(-100).(int); ok {
        i += w
    }
    fmt.Println("i =", i)
}

Output:
i = 49
```

It uses [Type assertions](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_assertions).

Comment: you're absolutely right!  thanks!  do you have any insight on types string representations of types?

Comment: Check out `reflect.TypeOf`.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring That at least answers the question in the topics title. This answer not. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 172):

You also can do type switches:

```
switch v := myInterface.(type) {
case int:
    // v is an int here, so e.g. v + 1 is possible.
    fmt.Printf("Integer: %v", v)
case float64:
    // v is a float64 here, so e.g. v + 1.0 is possible.
    fmt.Printf("Float64: %v", v)
case string:
    // v is a string here, so e.g. v + " Yeah!" is possible.
    fmt.Printf("String: %v", v)
default:
    // And here I'm feeling dumb. ;)
    fmt.Printf("I don't know, ask stackoverflow.")
}
```

Comment: thank you for that.  but still not quite there.  in the example, how to I coerce var w into an int?

Comment: Mue's example does the same thing, but in a type switch instead of an if statement. In the 'case int', 'v' will be an integer. in 'case float64', 'v' will be a float64, etc.

Comment: right.  had forgotten syntax var.(type), which is sneaky and cool

Comment: When working with maps of maps, given myMap as map[string]map[string]string, myMap.(type) seems to never be matched as map[string]string but always as map[string]interface{}
https://goplay.tools/snippet/SW9BARA_-Fy

Answer (score 66):

You can use reflection (`reflect.TypeOf()`) to get the type of something, and the value it gives (`Type`) has a string representation (`String` method) that you can print.

Comment: And if you just want to get a string or a type (e.g. for printing in the default block of a type switch link in [Mue's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6373523/55504) you can just use `fmt`'s "%T" format instead of directly using `reflect`.

Answer (score 19):

Here is an example of decoding a generic map using both switch and reflection, so if you don't match the type, use reflection to figure it out and then add the type in next time.

```
var data map[string]interface {}

...

for k, v := range data {
    fmt.Printf("pair:%s\t%s\n", k, v)   

    switch t := v.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("Integer: %v\n", t)
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("Float64: %v\n", t)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("String: %v\n", t)
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("Bool: %v\n", t)
    case []interface {}:
        for i,n := range t {
            fmt.Printf("Item: %v= %v\n", i, n)
        }
    default:
        var r = reflect.TypeOf(t)
        fmt.Printf("Other:%v\n", r)             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways to get a string representation of a type. Switches can also be used with user types:

```golang
var user interface{}
user = User{name: "Eugene"}

// .(type) can only be used inside a switch
switch v := user.(type) {
case int:
    // Built-in types are possible (int, float64, string, etc.)
    fmt.Printf("Integer: %v", v)
case User:
    // User defined types work as well  
    fmt.Printf("It's a user: %s\n", user.(User).name)
}

// You can use reflection to get *reflect.rtype
userType := reflect.TypeOf(user)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", userType)

// You can also use %T to get a string value
fmt.Printf("%T", user)

// You can even get it into a string
userTypeAsString := fmt.Sprintf("%T", user)

if userTypeAsString == "main.User" {
    fmt.Printf("\nIt's definitely a user")
}
```

Link to a playground: https://play.golang.org/p/VDeNDUd9uK6

Answer (score 8):

Type switches can also be used with reflection stuff:

```
var str = "hello!"
var obj = reflect.ValueOf(&str)

switch obj.Elem().Interface().(type) {
case string:
    log.Println("obj contains a pointer to a string")
default:
    log.Println("obj contains something else")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to offer up a way to return a boolean based on passing an argument of a reflection Kinds to a local type receiver (because I couldn't find anything like this).

First, we declare our anonymous type of type reflect.Value:

```
type AnonymousType reflect.Value
```

Then we add a builder for our local type AnonymousType which can take in any potential type (as an interface):

```
func ToAnonymousType(obj interface{}) AnonymousType {
    return AnonymousType(reflect.ValueOf(obj))
}
```

Then we add a function for our AnonymousType struct which asserts against a reflect.Kind:

```
func (a AnonymousType) IsA(typeToAssert reflect.Kind) bool {
    return typeToAssert == reflect.Value(a).Kind()
}
```

This allows us to call the following:

```
var f float64 = 3.4

anon := ToAnonymousType(f)

if anon.IsA(reflect.String) {
    fmt.Println("Its A String!")
} else if anon.IsA(reflect.Float32) {
    fmt.Println("Its A Float32!")
} else if anon.IsA(reflect.Float64) {
    fmt.Println("Its A Float64!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Failed")
}
```

Can see a longer, working version here:https://play.golang.org/p/EIAp0z62B7

Answer (score 4):

You can use

1. Printf("%T", interface{})
2. reflect.TypeOf
3. reflect.ValueOf(x).Kind()

**-> reflect:**

```
 func typeofobject(x interface{}){
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(x))
 }
```

**-> Printf()**

```
 // Golang program to find the variable type
    package main
    
    // importing required packages
    import (
      "fmt"
    )
    
    // main function
    func main() {
      f := true
      st := ""
      a := 1
      d := 1.0
      arr := []string{"Go", "Is", "Fun"}
    
      fmt.Printf("%T\n", f)
      fmt.Printf("%T\n", st)
      fmt.Printf("%T\n", a)
      fmt.Printf("%T\n", d)
      fmt.Printf("%T\n", arr)
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
bool
string
int
float64
[]string
```

**-> reflect.ValueOf(x).Kind())**

```
func typeofobject(x interface{}){
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(x).Kind())
}
```

source: [geeks-for-geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-find-the-type-of-an-object-in-golang/)