# Can I compare variable types with .(type) in Golang?

Tags: go, types

I'm quite confused about the .(type) syntax for interface variables. Is it possible to use it like this:

```
var a,b interface{}
// some code
if first.(type) == second.(type) {
}
```

or is reflect.TypeOf() the only option to check if the underlying types of a and b are the same type? What comparison am I making in the code above?

Comment: *What comparison am I making in the code above?* None, because it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`someInterface.(type)` is *only used* in type switches. In fact if you tried to run that you'd see that in the error message.

```
func main() {
    var a, b interface{}
    a = 1
    b = 1

    fmt.Println(a.(type) == b.(type))
}
```

> prog.go:10: use of .(type) outside type switch

What you could do instead is `a.(int) == b.(int)`, which is really no different from `int(a) == int(b)`

```
func main() {
    var a, b interface{}
    a = 1
    b = 1

    fmt.Println(a.(int) == b.(int))
}
```

> true

Comment: Note that the second example will panic if both variables are not of type `int`.

Comment: The question is about comparing types, not about comparing values of the same type.

Comment: What does the second code have to do with the question?

Comment: So the question is "Is it possible to use .(type) like this? ..." and the answer given above is NO.  But if you want to do that you can do it like this.  Granted the .(int) thing is a little weird, and the panic thing is a problem.  But this is the only answer that does answer the question.

Answer (score 21):

```
func isType(a, b interface{}) bool {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%T", a) == fmt.Sprintf("%T", b)
}
```

The `"%T"` fmt option uses reflection under the hood, which would make the above statement practically that same as:

```
func isType(a, b interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.TypeOf(a) == reflect.TypeOf(b)
}
```

Either one would work, and won't cause a panic trying to utilize any kind of type assertion like some of the other suggestions.

Comment: Using Sprintf could be incorrect. Both of these are not equivalent. Say, if you have 2 pkgs: pkgA/config & pkgB/config. If you compare the type with Sprintf, ie. `config.int == config.int`, they would be equal, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

You'd need to specify the type. That syntax is used to make [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) about interfaces, not about checking the specific type.
You'll have to use `reflect.TypeOf` for that.

You can view this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373426/249552) for a proper use of type assertions.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
for key, value := range data {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println(key, value, "(string)")
    case float64:
        fmt.Println(key, value, "(float64)")
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println(key, value, "(interface)")
    }
 }
```

...
and you can use for all types in any interface...

Comment: Similar syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26976477/12817546