# How to get the pointer to a struct passed through interface{} in golang?

Tags: pointers, go, interface

> No, I don't think this is a duplicate of 
>    [How to determine an interface{} value's "real" type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372474/how-to-determine-an-interface-values-real-type). I know how to get the Type of an interface variable, but I can't find a way to get the pointer to an interface{}'s real type.

Recently, I got into trouble with `interface{}`. I have a variable with type A been passed through `interface{}`, a method `Tt` is defined with *A as the receiver.

I want to call the method `Tt` but failed because the variable is in an `interface{}` and I can't get the pointer to the variable.

As you can see, `reflect.TypeOf(v)` gives the correct type `A`, but `reflect.TypeOf(&v)` gives `*interface {}` instead of `*A`.

Is there any way to get `*A`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type SomeStruct1 struct{
}

type SomeStruct2 struct{
}

type SomeStruct3 struct{
}
etc...

func (*SomeStruct1) SomeMethod(){
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
func (*SomeStruct2) SomeMethod(){
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
func (*SomeStruct3) SomeMethod(){
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
etc...

func DoSomething(arg interface{}){
    switch v:=b.(type){
        []byte:{
            dosomething for []byte
        }
        default:{
            var m reflect.Value
            if value.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
                m = reflect.ValueOf(&v).MethodByName("SomeMethod")
            } else {
                m = reflect.ValueOf(v).MethodByName("SomeMethod")
            }
            m.Call(nil)
        }
}

func main() {
    DoSomething([]byte{...})
    DoSomething(SomeStruct1{})
    DoSomething(&SomeStruct1{})
    etc..
}
```

Comment: using the reflection package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine an interface{} value's "real" type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372474/how-to-determine-an-interface-values-real-type)

Comment: Why don't you just put the method `Tt` in the interface and be done? Without using any reflection?

Comment: please provide an example where this would be justified. Even intend here seems wrong to me

Comment: @Yerken, I have edit to give a more detailed example. I want the function `DoSomething` accepts both `SomeStruct` and `*SomeStruct`

Answer (score 8):

Use reflection:

```
//
// Return a pointer to the supplied struct via interface{}
//
func to_struct_ptr(obj interface{}) interface{} {
    vp := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(obj))
    vp.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(obj))
    return vp.Interface()
}
```

Pass in an `interface` with `T`, then you can get an `interface` with `*T`

Answer (score 3):

To call the pointer method `Tt()`, you must have an `*A` (or take the address of an [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) `A` value).  The `A` value in variable `b` is not [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), and therefore the `A` pointer methods are not accessible through `b`.

The fix is to start with the address of `a`:

```
var a A
var b interface{}
b = &a // Note change on this line
switch v := b.(type) {
default:
    reflect.ValueOf(v).MethodByName("Tt").Call(nil)
}
```

In the call `reflect.ValueOf(v)`, the value in `v` is passed as the argument. The `ValueOf` function unpacks the empty interface to recover a value of type `A`.

In the call `reflect.ValueOf(&v)`, an `*interface{}` is stored in the empty interface, which is then passed as the argument. The `ValueOf` function unpacks the empty interface to recover a value of type `*interface{}`. This is the address of the variable `v`, not the address of the variable `a`.

Reflection is not required in this specific example:

```
var a A
var b interface{}
b = &a
switch v := b.(type) {
case interface {
    Tt()
}:
    v.Tt()
default:
    fmt.Println("not handled")
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But I do think it's weird that `reflect.ValueOf(v)` gives `A` while `reflect.ValueOf(&v)` gives `* interface{}`

Comment: I added more explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need just type cast.
Example:

```
type SomeStruct1 struct{
    someList []string
}

func (s *SomeStruct1) print() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", s.someList)
...

func Call(T interface{}){
    switch T.(type){
    case *SomeStruct1:
        t := T.(*SomeStruct1) // cast as pointer to struct
        t.print()
    ...
    }
}

func main() {
    a := SomeStruct{
        someList: []string{"a", "b"}
    }
    Call(&a) // pass a as ptr
}
```